# Console app running under windows 10 iot core running on raspberry pi 2 cannot find assembly

Tags: .net, winapi, console-application, windows-10-iot-core

i'm running a dot net console app on a raspberry pi 2 and win 10 iot core.  It is not a universal windows app.

I can run the console app if it is a simple 'hello world' app.  The problem arises when I try to include external assemblies (such as nLog).  When I include these external assemblies, I start to get errors like 'cannot find file'.

anyone have an idea on how to run a real-world console app on win 10 iot core?

Comment: Are you using Nuget?

Comment: Yes, using Nuget to get the nLog package.

Comment: You MUST use the CORE .NET packaged versions. Not sure if there are any yet...